# File upload through sampler "body data" section in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

Is there any way to upload a file (like - pdf file) through Sampler "Body Data" section in JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

There is, via [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString)

[image]

More information on [JMeter Functions concept: Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)

However I don't think it's the correct way to upload the file (unless you're building a [multipart request body](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt) manually for some reason)

So I would rather recommend recording your file upload request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), given you will have the file in JMeter's "bin" folder during the recording it will generate proper [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager).

Comment: Hi @Dmitri , thanks for the comment. Actually I am trying to build a multipart request body  manually so that's why I need to know if there is any process to upload a file through sampler "body data" section.